# derivation of L2 norm of matrix formula

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

consider a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, its L-2 norm is defined as the maximum eigenvalue of $A^T A$. I tried to derive this from $||A||_2=\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{||Ax||_2}{||x||_2}=\max_{x\neq 0}\sqrt{\frac{x^TA^TAx}{x^Tx}}$ and don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using eigendecomposition of a matrix, you can write
$A^T A= Q \Lambda Q^{-1} $ where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal maxtrix of Eigenvalues of $A^T A$ and $Q$ is the matrix of the corresponding eigenvectors.

First, note that without loss of generality, you can concentrate on the case $||x||_2=1$. Let $y= Qx$, then $||y||^2 = y^Ty=(Qx)^T(Qx)=x^TQ^TQx=x^TQ^{-1}Qx=x^Tx=||x||^2=1$.

Now, your max is $\max_{y: ||y||_2=1} y^T \Lambda y=\max_{y: ||y||_2=1} \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i y^2_i$, where $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues.

I hope that you can conclude from here.

**Edit:** the eigendecomposition of $A^T A$ holds true under some conditions, for instance, $A$ has full column rank.